# HTTP request to orchid throws Warning

Tags: java, proxy, warnings, tor

I am working with orchid library and this is my code:

(...)

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS,new InetSocketAddress("localhost",9150));
httpUrlConnetion = (HttpURLConnection) website.openConnection(proxy);
httpUrlConnetion.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","any user-agent");
httpUrlConnetion.setConnectTimeout(5000);
httpUrlConnetion.setReadTimeout(20000);
return Jsoup.parse(IOUtils.toString(httpUrlConnetion.getInputStream()));
```

And I am getting this warning:

WARNING: Your application is giving Orchid only an IP address.  Applications that do DNS resolves themselves may leak information. Consider using Socks4a (e.g. via privoxy or socat) instead.  For more information please see https://wiki.torproject.org/TheOnionRouter/TorFAQ#SOCKSAndDNS

I started on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171643/java-tor-lib-how-to-setup-orchid-tor-lib-with-java) to setup orchid.
I see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268878/how-to-stop-java-from-preresolving-my-host-while-browsing-via-proxy-tor) but dind't get it working under http.
How to solve it? or any other way to easy use Tor with java?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your mentioned thread you are using the URL class for resolving the URL to an IP adddress which will use the Native DNS-resolving technique (which is not tunneled through Tor).
You could use [SilverTunnel-NG](https://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel-ng/) instead, this will also do the DNS-resolving over Tor.

Check out an example implementation [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel-ng/wiki/Sample%20Code%20%3A%20Check%20if%20Tor%20Connection%20works/).

Comment: Yeah, that's good, thanks,  but I also want to create multiple tor circuits at different local ports (ex 9150, 9250, 9350, etc), I didn't see how to do this with Silver Tunnel-NG